# Clean up bower_components for production

Tags: deployment, bower, web-deployment, production-environment

I use bower to manage the client-side dependencies in a Polymer project.

The problem I have is that some elements pull in a lot of stuff which is not needed in prod, and maybe not even while developing.

E.g. one component ships a demo .mp4 and .jpeg file increasing the size by almost 7 MB.

Is there a best practice to clean up the bower_component folder from unneeded stuff?